# Google CloudPrint printing infinite copies (Android)

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

I have been using Google CloudPrint since December, and suddenly (sometimes, mostly when the networks is slow) when printing, it keeps printing.

I am using this configuration: Android Phone, my App creates a print job with ticket via Google CloudPrint, the android notification center displays the print job "Printing" (as in sending...), the Google CloudPrint receives the task, and prints it with the printer associated, then, normally, it removes the print job from the notification center. and thats all.

Now, it stays in the notification center... for ever, even if you cancel, it already sent a lot of print jobs (they are slow to appear on the GoogleCloud panel).

Is there a bug with Google CloudPrint or is a problem with my (probably outdated now) code?

I know is Beta, and that, but i neither find documentation, known bugs, or anything at all.

If you can guide me in solving this problem...

(This is the code i use to send the intent)

```
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(Context);
photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
photoPrinter.printBitmap("print job", bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.  I uninstalled Cloud Print and then reinstalled.  Fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you :) i will try this and vote if it fixes this.